Making sense of どうかこうか凌いで来たように客が来る
From Kokoro chapter 21:

父はかねてから腎臓を病んでいた。中年以後の人にしばしば見る通り、父のこの病は慢性であった。その代り要心さえしていれば急変のないものと当人も家族のものも信じて疑わなかった。現に父は養生のお蔭一つで、今日までどうかこうか凌いで来たように客が来ると吹聴していた。

I don't get how the bold sentence is understood. I think 今日までどうかこうか凌いで来た means "managed to endure the illness until today" but I have no idea what ように客が来る is supposed to mean. Does ように mean "as if"? 客が来る means "visitors come"?

This sentence indeed smells like a garden path sentence. It would be a lot easier to understand if it was "現に父は客が来ると、養生のお蔭一つで今日までどうかこうか凌いで来たというように吹聴していた".


現に父は〔養生のお蔭一つで、今日までどうかこうか凌いで来たように〕（客が来ると）吹聴していた。

I think the と means "when". 「客が来ると」 here means "when a visitor comes" or "every time a visitor comes" ≈「客が来たら」「客が来たときには」or「客が来るたびに」.
養生のお蔭一つで、今日までどうかこうか凌いで来た is the rough content of what father told to the visitors. I think the ように means "(things) like" or "(spoke) as if". cf. 「～と言う」 "say (what's actually said)" vs 「～ように言う」 "say (rough content)"
"When my father had a visitor, he told them things like / spoke to them as if he had managed to endure the illness until today only by taking care of his health."

Thank you, that と was a red herring...
